# How to get the length of a unicode string?

Tags: python

If I do the following:

```
ustr = unicode()
ustr = '青皮'    
print len(ustr)
```

I get an output of `6`. But that's the number of bytes.

How do I get an output of `2`? (i.e. the actual number of unicode code points)

Comment: @Bhargav Rao - i don't think either of those 2 answers given to that question, will actually answer mine.

Comment: The dupe perfectly answers your post. Try `len(__import__('unicodedata').normalize('NFC',u'青皮'))`.

Comment: the answer seems to be to create the unicode object as: `ustr = unicode(<"青皮">, 'utf-8'). And then `len(ustr)` gives me the number of code points.